# JQuery D3 what is good storing selection in a variable or again using the selection next time

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I use jquery and d3 in my project. I want to know whats the best practice, is it good to store the selection in a variable to be used in the different function for e.g.

```
        var selectedElement = $("#someElement");

        // now use that same variable to do the operation 
        function func1()
        {
            selectedElement.style("background", "red");

        }

        // now use that same variable to do the operation 
        function func2() {
            selectedElement.style("boundary", "1");
        }
```

or Just selecting it at that point in the function .

```
// new selection 
        function func1()
        {
            $("#someElement").style("background", "red");

        }

        // new selection
        function func2() {
            $("#someElement").style("boundary", "1");
        }
```

I read somewhere that second option is good as first option may cause memory leak, or increase the memory footprint.

what is good.  !!!! I hope same will be applicable to d3 also.

Comment: Depends on how much `func1()` and `func2()` are called. Also if the selector changes you have to update it two places instead of one, but that's not a performance thing.

Comment: thanks anything related to memory

Comment: JQuery and D3 selections are different things, so there's no single answer for both. In particular, when using data to update the visualization with D3, you *have to* reselect or update the selection.